# Huffman C Infinite Loop

Tags: c, arrays, queue, huffman-code

I have this Huffman Code that is meant to return the Huffman code for each letter in the array and print them in alphabetical order. The problem is that it generates no output and instead carries on processing until I exit it manually. Can anyone please help me identify the error? I think my code is correct but I don't know where the infinite loop is coming from.

```
void buildHuffmanTree(char arr[], int freq[]){
    int top = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
        push(PQ,newNode(arr[i],freq[i]));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<qTop;i++){
        struct node* node2 = newNode('!',0);
        node2->left = pop(PQ);
        node2->right = pop(PQ);
        struct node* nodeL=node2->left;
        struct node* nodeR=node2->right;
        node2->frequency = nodeL->frequency + nodeR->frequency;
        push(PQ,node2);
    }
    struct node* root= pop(PQ);
    printCodes(root,arr2,top);
}

int main(){

    char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' }; 
    int freq[] = { 5, 9, 12, 13, 16, 45 }; 

    buildHuffmanTree(arr,freq);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I am expecting is this. But instead it just keep on running, while not outputting anything. I am sure that it is pushing values into the PQ properly so I don't know where my error is.

```
a: 1100
b: 1101
c: 100
d: 101
e: 111
f: 0
```

I would appreciate any kind of advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Comment: Also, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane I accidentally deleted the ')' when pasting it here. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big problem:

```
for (int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function expects the argument to be a pointer to the first character of a ***null-terminated*** byte string.

Your character array is *not* a null-terminated string, which means the `strlen` function will go out of bounds attempting to find the terminator. Going out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A simple solution is to use a literal string as initializer for the array:

```
char arr[] = "abcdef";  // Make arr a null-terminated string
```

Another and perhaps more generic solution is to pass the length of the array to the functions that need it, and use that argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick run. Seems like your program has ran into a infinity loop, where the left will never be as NULL.

```
#0  0x0000564d16bd086f in minHeapify (node=0x564d1739d340) at huffman.c:44
        right = 0x564d1739d300
        root = 21
        currentNode = 0x564d1739d320
        left = 0x564d1739d300
#1  0x0000564d16bd0a62 in pop (PQ=0x564d16e95540 <PQ>) at huffman.c:88
        node = 0x564d1739d2c0
#2  0x0000564d16bd0c2d in buildHuffmanTree (arr=0x7ffce3f795b2 "abcdef", freq=0x7ffce3f79590) at huffman.c:123
        node2 = 0x564d1739d360
        nodeL = 0x564d1739d2e0
        nodeR = 0x564d1739d320
        i = 2
        top = 0
        root = 0x0
#3  0x0000564d16bd0d3e in main () at huffman.c:139
        arr = "abcdef"
        freq = {5, 9, 12, 13, 16, 45}
```

**How to debug**

Compile your source with:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb huffman.c -o huffman
```

Now run it:

```
./huffman
```

It will get stuck.

Open another command line, run:

```
ps aux | grep "PID\|huffman"
```

Remember the PID value of your huffman process.

Now fun gdb as root:

```
sudo gdb
```

Attach to your huffman process:

```
attach $your_huffman_pid
```

Run following to check the call stack:

```
bt full
```

For more information: [GDB cookbook](http://savannah.gnu.org/cookbook/?group=gdb)